# How do I change user name on Gitlab Contributors without losing commits

Tags: git, gitlab

I have noticed that all contributors on the company gitlab use the format Name Surname, while I have name.surname. Is there a way to change the user name and not create any discrepancy?
For example appearing on the Contributors page as two separate contributors, Name Surname and name.surname, or not having commits credited to the changed user name Name Surname, or authentication problems when using git commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your username should not affect associations of commits to your user account. Commits are tied to email addresses based on your local git settings. Anything tied to your user (such as assignments) should auto-update.

The main things that are affected:

1. Profile link.
2. Project links. Basically, any links starting with: `gitlab.example.com/USERNAME/PROJECT-PATH`.
3. Any previous mentions of your username (such as in comments) will no longer link to your profile page or provide hover information.
4. Any authentication based on your username needs to be updated. For example, if you're using git with HTTPS, then you need to update the username portion.

For any links (profile, project) tied to your username, when someone visits them in a browser, they'll be automatically redirected *until* someone takes your old username. In most other cases, you'll need to update the URLs.